# Popup windows in jQuery

Tags: jquery, popup, modal-dialog

I had a code which was working somehow, but now, when I'm trying to rewrite my scripts suddenly I got wrong X and Y positions of popup window.
This is the first problem.

Next problem is that this code is quite bad, because I always got some bugs when displaying popup windows. It's kind of hard to explain, you'd better look at the code.

The main thing is: a have an element (lets say a picture), when mousehover fires I need to keep the window shown when my mouse is over the window. Another words - I must be able to copy some information from that window. So I wrote a code but it's quite buggy, and now except bugs I got wrong X and Y positions. Look:

```
    $(".infoBox").die();
$(".infoBox").live('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
        $("#infoBox").html("");
        $("#infoBox")
          .css('top', (e.pageY - 10) + 'px')
          .css('left', (e.pageX - 20) + 'px');

        setTimeout(showInfoBox, 500);

        ID = $(this).attr('id');    

        if ($(this).hasClass("companyInfo"))    { showCompanyInfo(ID); }
        if ($(this).hasClass("userInfo"))       { showUserInfo(ID);    }

    } else {
        setTimeout(hideInfoBox, 1000);
    }
});

function showInfoBox() {
    $("#infoBox").fadeIn('slow');
}

function hideInfoBox() {
    if (mouse_in_infoBox == 0) {
        $("#infoBox").hide();
        $("#infoBox").html("");
    }
};

$("#infoBox").hover(
    function() {
        mouse_in_infoBox = 1;
    },
    function() {
        mouse_in_infoBox = 0;
        setTimeout(hideInfoBox, 1000);
    }
);
```

So I have, for example

```
<img class="infoBox" id="company_id_which_was_dynamically_added">
```

and showCompanyInfo has

```
"$("infoBox").html(...)".
```

In my index.php I got , and the CSS is:

```
#infoBox {
display: none;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid #CDFF00;
background-color: #1C1F1A;
color: #CCCC33;
padding: 10px;
z-index: 5;
max-width: 400px;
min-width: 50px;
min-height: 50px;
}
```

Ah, yes, another question is related to live and die methods. In my site I have a lot of tabs, and when I'm switching them I put handlers like .click/.hover on some elements. And here I use .live method, because my tabs use ajax. But when I switch tabs several times, I got same several handlers, for example if I show a lightbox I got several lightboxes. Now I use .die() before .live(), but It seems that this is not a good solution at all...

I will really appreciate any help, because I tried to make these popup windows several times and always got some bugs. In my code above if you will move your mouse clickly you'll got empty windows and other bad things.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a quick suggestion. It may not be appropriate. but i would use .position() and grab out the direction you want. At the moment you are grabbing the CSS top and left. This is fine if they are positioned absolutely. But position will do it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that appear to be incorrect here but its hard to tell exactly whats going on without seeing more of your code and getting some more information. What version of jQuery are you using, what browsers are you having the problem with, and does the problem exist on all browsers or only specific ones?

According to [the jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/live/) live() is deprecated as of version 1.7 and the [on() event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be used instead. Perhaps your issues are related to using the live handler.

Another thing that could solve your incorrect pageX value is to check that e.pageX is in fact an integer (maybe use parseInt(e.pageX, 10) to make sure it is an integer). I have had strange problems with variables that should be integers but end up being strings for some reason. Now I make sure I declare all integers as integers (using parseInt()) and don't allow javascript to decide on its own.

Also this part of your code doesn't make any sense:

```
$("#infoBox").hover(
    function() {
        mouse_in_infoBox = 1;
    },
    function() {
        mouse_in_infoBox = 0;
        setTimeout(hideInfoBox, 1000);
    }
);
```

The value of mouse_in_infoBox will always be 0.

Another problem I see is that you have inconsistencies with your selectors for infoBox. Is infoBox a class $('.infoBox') or is it an id $('#infoBox')? Based on the code you gave us above you have many incorrect selectors. Any reference to infoBox should be $('.infoBox') and not $('#infoBox'). Also your CSS applies to id #infoBox so not sure whether thats intentional or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `live()` is not deprecated, it's discouraged to be used and you can still use `live()`, 1.7+ just uses an alias to `on()` with `live()`.

Comment: @ lolwut: Fair enough. I was only stating what is mentioned on the jQuery website (http://api.jquery.com/live/): "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."